# php trim string

Tags: php, trim

Say I have a string called `$string`, it could be a whole article of writing or just a couple of sentences.

I'd like to trim it to just the text about 50 chars to the left of, and 50 to the right of a phrase named `$word` within it.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use strpos() to locate the string, and then substr() to obtain the range of characters you want.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help. Check if you character at position $i is included.
I didn't check.

```
$i = strpos($string, $word);
if ($i!==FALSE)
{
    $phrase = substr($string, $i-50,$i) . substr($string, $i,$i+50);
}
```